# Breadcrumbs Incorrect URL Path

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, url, alias

Using Joomla 3.9.12 and [SP Portfolio](https://www.joomshaper.com/joomla-extensions/sp-simple-portfolio) v1.7

I have a menu item called `Locations`, this is a menu item type *SP Simple Portfolio » Items*

Whenever I visit `example.com/locations` I can see all my portfolio items, great. If I select one of the portfolio items, e.g. Paris, I am taken to `example.com/locations/paris`, works as expected.

I have enabled the Joomla breadcrumbs module on this page and it displays;

> You are here: Home / Locations / Paris

- Selecting `Home` successfully takes me to the home page `example.com`
- Selecting `Locations` takes me to `example.com/locations/items` - this page doesn't exist so I get a 404 error.

When I select `Locations` in the breadcrumbs I want to go to `example.com/locations`.

No idea where the additional `/items` URL parameter is coming from, I can't see it configured anywhere in my menu setup.

What do I need to do in order to get this working how I want?

Comment: This seems like an intelligent workaround: https://www.yellowwebmonkey.com/developer-blog/item/move-website-remove-folder-name-from-path .  This looks kinda close: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/22827/12352

Comment: Do you have any SEF extensions installed? I get completely different results on a clean installation. Clicking on an item takes me to `example.com/locations/item/1-paris` and breadcrumb only contains `Home > Locations`. And `Locations` is not clickable.

Comment: @Sharky I don't have any third party SEF extensions installed. Joomshaper have created an override of `mod_breadcrumbs` I might try to edit this, although I don't think I should have to :/

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa those are both good suggestions. I'm kind of reluctant to create any url rewrites as it can get messy. I've already tired creating a hidden menu item called `items` with menu item alias to `locations` but it doesn't work. I can't understand why the breadcrumbs is displaying `/items` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by editing the (already existing Helix / Joomshaper) override.

After spending a (very!) long time trying to figure out where the `/items` url parameter was coming from, I gave up and modified the override.

I know this isn't a solution but it solves my problem, and possibly someone else that uses the Helix framework or a Joomshaper template.

Add this code to `your-template\html\mod_breadcrumbs\default.php`, before the `foreach` block.

```
array_walk($list, function (&$v) { 
    if ($v->name == 'Items') $v->link = dirname($v->link); 
});
```

The breadcrumbs code returns an array with `name` and `link` keys. This checks the `link` and if it contains `Items`, it will be removed.

Working so far..

Comment: Just so you know, there are a few fundamental differences between arrays and objects.  A sneaky difference is that an object doesn't need the `&` (modify by reference) declaration to remain mutated outside of the `array_walk()` scope.  Have a look at this: https://3v4l.org/cbIHX

Answer (score 0):

That make me crazy and took long time to solve.

Add `rtrim($item->link,"items")` before `class="pathway"`.

Detail is as follows:

```
echo '<a href="' . rtrim($item->link,"items") . '" class="pathway">' . $item->name . '</a>';
```

Comment: This technique is generally inadvisable.  The second parameter of `rtrim()` is a character mask.  In other words, it is a list of individual characters to remove.  It would work identically if the mask was `stime`. This can lead to unwanted side effects if the last word in the string is not `items` but contains `i`, `t`, `e`, `m`, or `s`. It would be better to specify the literal substring to remove at the end of the string (if it exists).  Please take the [tour].